# Input empty set value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with an input I have. If I change a value of a certain element an input gets emptied which gives me trouble saving the article.

Now is there code to catch the emptying of the input, and if that happens fill it with another value of another textinput which resides next to it.

I have the following code, but that doesn't get called when the value of the input changes to nothing, gets emptied:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.querySelector('input#created').onchange=changeCreatedDate;
},false);

function changeCreatedDate(event){

    var pubup = jQuery("#publish_up").val();
    jQuery("input#created").val(pubup);

}
```

Because this didn't work I tried something else, but that is also not called when the input gets emptied.

```
$("input#created").on("change paste keyup", function() {
        var pubup = jQuery("#publish_up").val();
        jQuery("input#created").val(pubup);
    });
```

EDIT: The code actually works when I call it with a keuyp or a change event that I know works. The problem lies in the fact that the code DOES NOT get called. I don't know why, maybe because the change is not registered. How can I make sure the computer sees the change, what function do i need to use.

Comment: If its a text input, you can try `.on('input', ...)` event. But it should have worked for `keyup`. So the real question is, is this input being created dynamically?

Comment: @Huub S kindly update snippet

Comment: No it gets dynamically emptied. It's a bug in in a CMS. The code works though, because I manually activate it with keyup or something it gets executed. I just don't know how I can make the computer check if its empty, fill it.

Comment: @Dhaarani What do you mean?

Comment: if(jQuery("input#created").val()==0){}

Comment: Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oqnfo1Lu/5/

Comment: OK, a possible problem could be that the input is on another tab, which is hidden when the input gets changed...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method and also you can use [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) since you are selecting by id :)

Try this code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('created').addEventListener('input', changeCreatedDate);
}, false);

function changeCreatedDate(event) {
  if(this.value === ""){
    this.value = document.getElementById('publish_up').value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="publish_up" id="publish_up" value="2017-03-21"> <br/><br/>

<p>Simply try to empty the value of the following input and it should get the value of the first one</p>
<input type="text" name="created" id="created" value="erase me ...">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use jQuery, it would work...!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#second').on('change keyup paste', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).val($('#first').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" type="text" name="" value="Some text here">
<input id="second" type="text" name="" value="">
```